# Rails, find by associated record.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application I have two models:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  #it has field city:string
  has_one :address
end
```

Now I want to find all Locations which address city field have value: "test". How can I do that? Thank's in advance.

Comment: Please be clear.Which table has the `city` field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Location.includes(:address).where(city: "test")
```

Answer (score 3):

Since nobody else bothered to explain why you would use `includes` vs `joins`:

Assume data:

```
addr1 = Address.create(street: "1 Unique Street", city: "test")
addr2 = Address.create(street: "2 Unique Street", city: "test")
Location.create(name: "Location 1", address: addr1)
```

Joins:

```
Location.joins(:address).where(addresses: { city: "test" })

# performs INNER JOIN
#> [#<Location id: 1, name: "Location 1">,
     #<Location id: 1, name: "Location 1">]
```

Includes:

```
Location.includes(:address).where(addresses: { city: "test" })

# performs LEFT OUTER JOIN
#> [#<Location id: 1, name: "Location 1">]
```

If you use `joins`, use `distinct`:

```
Location.joins(:address).where(addresses: { city: "test" }).distinct(:location)

#> [#<Location id: 1, name: "Location 1">]
```

The reason is because of the `INNER JOIN` that `joins` performs. See more information here: [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

```
Location.joins(:address).where(addresses: {city: "test"})
```

Comment: Better to use `includes` rather than `joins`.

Comment: @Pavan Using `includes` would be more complicated because you'd need a `references` too, you'd left join unnecessarily, and you'd eager-load addresses, which isn't explicitly needed here. Why not just use `joins`?

Comment: @gwcoffey Yup!But `joins` creates duplicates